# Install windows service using DSC (Desired State Configuration)

Tags: java, powershell, command-line, dsc

**Epilogue:** 
*With dsc-resource "service", installing a service is straightforward. 
Or programs that come with MSI packages. Once they are installed, via default they also install a windows service. [posh: get-service *etc]*

What I am trying to do! 
Usually from the java root directory I install tomcat service via:

> CMD> bin\service.bat install /user=StarDestroyer\

Would like to use DSC [Desired State Configuration] to install a tomcat service. It is a small part of a bigger automation task I am working on. I have not seen many command line examples of this.

Additional Info: ***Service.bat*** looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "SELF=%~dp0%service.bat"
rem Guess CATALINA_HOME if not defined
set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
if not "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "" goto gotHome
set "CATALINA_HOME=%cd%"
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat8.exe" goto okHome
rem CD to the upper dir
cd ..
set "CATALINA_HOME=%cd%"
:gotHome
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat8.exe" goto okHome
echo The tomcat8.exe was not found...
echo The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.
echo This environment variable is needed to run this program
goto end
:okHome
rem Make sure prerequisite environment variables are set
if not "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto gotJdkHome
if not "%JRE_HOME%" == "" goto gotJreHome
echo Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
echo Service will try to guess them from the registry.
goto okJavaHome
:gotJreHome
if not exist "%JRE_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not exist "%JRE_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe" goto noJavaHome
goto okJavaHome
:gotJdkHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\java.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\javaw.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not "%JRE_HOME%" == "" goto okJavaHome
set "JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%\jre"
goto okJavaHome
:noJavaHome
echo The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
echo This environment variable is needed to run this program
echo NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
goto end
:okJavaHome
if not "%CATALINA_BASE%" == "" goto gotBase
set "CATALINA_BASE=%CATALINA_HOME%"
:gotBase

set "EXECUTABLE=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat8.exe"

rem Set default Service name
set SERVICE_NAME=StarDestroyer
set DISPLAYNAME=StarDestroyer

if "x%1x" == "xx" goto displayUsage
set SERVICE_CMD=%1
shift
if "x%1x" == "xx" goto checkServiceCmd
:checkUser
if "x%1x" == "x/userx" goto runAsUser
if "x%1x" == "x--userx" goto runAsUser
set SERVICE_NAME=%1
set DISPLAYNAME=%1
shift
if "x%1x" == "xx" goto checkServiceCmd
goto checkUser
:runAsUser
shift
if "x%1x" == "xx" goto displayUsage
set SERVICE_USER=%1
shift
runas /env /savecred /user:%SERVICE_USER% "%COMSPEC% /K \"%SELF%\" %SERVICE_CMD% %SERVICE_NAME%"
goto end
:checkServiceCmd
if /i %SERVICE_CMD% == install goto doInstall
if /i %SERVICE_CMD% == remove goto doRemove
if /i %SERVICE_CMD% == uninstall goto doRemove
echo Unknown parameter "%SERVICE_CMD%"
:displayUsage
echo.
echo Usage: service.bat install/remove [service_name] [/user username]
goto end

:doRemove
rem Remove the service
echo Removing the service '%SERVICE_NAME%' ...
echo Using CATALINA_BASE:    "%CATALINA_BASE%"

"%EXECUTABLE%" //DS//%SERVICE_NAME% ^
    --LogPath "%CATALINA_BASE%\logs"
if not errorlevel 1 goto removed
echo Failed removing '%SERVICE_NAME%' service
goto end
:removed
echo The service '%SERVICE_NAME%' has been removed
goto end

:doInstall
rem Install the service
echo Installing the service '%SERVICE_NAME%' ...
echo Using CATALINA_HOME:    "%CATALINA_HOME%"
echo Using CATALINA_BASE:    "%CATALINA_BASE%"
echo Using JAVA_HOME:        "%JAVA_HOME%"
echo Using JRE_HOME:         "%JRE_HOME%"

rem Try to use the server jvm
set "JVM=%JRE_HOME%\bin\server\jvm.dll"
if exist "%JVM%" goto foundJvm
rem Try to use the client jvm
set "JVM=%JRE_HOME%\bin\client\jvm.dll"
if exist "%JVM%" goto foundJvm
echo Warning: Neither 'server' nor 'client' jvm.dll was found at JRE_HOME.
set JVM=auto
:foundJvm
echo Using JVM:              "%JVM%"

set "CLASSPATH=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\bootstrap.jar;%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
if not "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "%CATALINA_BASE%" set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"

"%EXECUTABLE%" //IS//%SERVICE_NAME% ^
    --Description "Apache Tomcat 8.0.18 Server - http://tomcat.apache.org/" ^
    --DisplayName "%DISPLAYNAME%" ^
    --Install "%EXECUTABLE%" ^
    --LogPath "%CATALINA_BASE%\logs" ^
    --StdOutput auto ^
    --StdError auto ^
    --Classpath "%CLASSPATH%" ^
    --Jvm "%JVM%" ^
    --StartMode jvm ^
    --StopMode jvm ^
    --StartPath "%CATALINA_HOME%" ^
    --StopPath "%CATALINA_HOME%" ^
    --StartClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap ^
    --StopClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap ^
    --StartParams start ^
    --StopParams stop ^
    --JvmOptions "-Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME%;-Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE%;-Djava.endorsed.dirs=%CATALINA_HOME%\endorsed;-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp;-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager;-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties;-Dconfig.file=%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\starDestroyer.conf" ^
    --JvmMs 3072 ^
    --JvmMx 12888
if not errorlevel 1 goto installed
echo Failed installing '%SERVICE_NAME%' service
goto end
:installed
echo The service '%SERVICE_NAME%' has been installed.

:end
cd "%CURRENT_DIR%"
```

Comment: Can you update your post to show the `service.bat`? That would help.

Comment: @Snake Not sure how this helps. Are changes required in here for Dsc to work.

Answer (score 0):

As your custom installation involves various steps and I am not aware of any resource in gallery currently providing this, you will need to write a custom DSC resource for this. You can find how to do this here: [Build Custom Windows PowerShell Desired State Configuration Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/authoringresource)

When you build it you can use the call operator i.e. `&` to invoke your bat file.